# differentiation of compiler switches for C and C++ compilation in SCONS

Tags: scons

Is there an easy way of this. For various reasons, our build requires us to pass different -D switches to our C++ and C compilations (or bits of the build break). scons seems to be under the impression you'll always use the same switches (there's only CPPDEFS and CPPINCLUDES)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also create one environment for C compilations, and another for C++ compilations. Each environment would then have the appropriate flags.

Comment: ticked as this answers my question nicely

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the `CPPDEFINES` construction variable, for which SCons prepends the `'-D'` in a portable manner, you can put the defines in `CFLAGS` (c only) and `CXXFLAGS` (c++ only). You'll have to add the `'-D'` by hand though.

The `CCFLAGS` construction variable applies to both c and c++ compilations.

Comment: I ended up doing something like that. Thanks.

Comment: if you add your comment as an answer, i'll accept it as such, it answers my problem better